# Нарисовать фигуру на css

Tags: css, css3

Есть фигура в дизайне
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел отрисовать её с помощью ксс
Вот что получилось
https://jsfiddle.net/4so5mf1t/

```
<div class="figure">

</div>

.figure{
width:500px;
height:50px;
background: linear-gradient(-185deg, #75a4c0 50%, #d6e4ec 51%);
}
```

Но как можно модернизировать, что бы была белая полоса между бгшками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получился вот такой вариант. Надеюсь, будет полезен.

[Кодперо](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/JXMzjV?editors=1100)

```css
.figure-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #d6e4ec;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top-peace {
  background: #75a4c0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 520px;
  transform: rotate(-5.5deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: -14px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure-container">
  <div class="top-peace"></div>
</div>
```